# Difference between fixedDelay() and fixedRate()

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, poller

What is the difference between `Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)` and `Pollers.fixedRate(5000)`  in spring integrations `Pollers`?

Answer (score 5):

There is a significant difference between fixed-rate and fixed-delay. With fixed-rate, it doesn’t matter how long the previous execution took, the next execution will happen when it was scheduled. With fixed-delay, the next execution will always happen x time after the previous finished, even if it was delayed.

[More info here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/spring-integration-poller-example/)

Comment: One small clarification; with `fixedRate`, the next poll will happen when it was scheduled or immediately, if the current poll task takes longer than that rate. In other words, there is only ever one poll in process at a time.